# returning type of errors from library packages

Tags: go, error-handling, shared-libraries

In https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Errors it says,

> Calling code would test for a special type of `error` by *using a type switch*

In https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/ErrorValueFAQ it says,

> If you currently compare errors using ==, *use `errors.Is` instead*
> `if errors.Is(err, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF)`

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to return such kind of errors from my library packages, so that my package consumers can do error checkings like

- `if errors.Is(err, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF)`
- `if errors.As(err, &e)`

Please help.

PS. the above question was made possible because of the following *initial* question:

[Go latest idiomatic error reporting approach from library packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518752/go-latest-idiomatic-error-reporting-approach-from-library-packages)

And the best answer to both questions is --
https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors

Comment: What have you tried? You can declare and export an error in your library, and consumers can reference it in their call to `errors.Is`: https://play.golang.org/p/UGNrwMhuSau. For `errors.As`, declare and export a type that implements the `error` interface.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the `errors` package documentation:

> The Unwrap, Is and As functions work on errors that may wrap other errors.

So the key is to implement `Unwrap` for your error types. This can be done in one of the following ways:

- Use `fmt.Errorf` with `%w`

```
return fmt.Errorf("Some error: %w",io.ErrUnexpectedEOF)
```

The returned error wraps the unexpected EOF error, so `errors.Is` and `errors.As` can unwrap it.

- Use a custom type:

```
type MyErrr struct {
 ...
  err error
}

func (err MyErr) Error() string {...}
func (err MyErr) Unwrap() error {return err.err}
```

Then:

```
return MyError{err:io.ErrUnexpectedEOF}
```

This will also be unwrapped to get the unexpected EOF.

Comment: Using a pointer receiver for methods on error types is more common, though.

Comment: @jub0bs, with a pointer receiver, `*T` is error but `T` is not, and the functions must return a pointer to the error struct.

Comment: What functions, and why would returning a pointer be a problem?

Comment: @jub0bs, the functions returning the error would need to return a pointer to the struct. Returning a pointer would not be a problem. But it would not be better than returning a value either, provided the error structure isn't large.

Comment: thanks. Just FTR, refer also to _"the best answer"_ in my OP.